# Angular6 - Prod build fails to access

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I'm converting my angular6 app to a pwa and facing some troubles.

When I run the app with ng serve, everythings works fine.

When I publish the app or run with ng serve --prod, the app open but fails to load the login screen with an error in the console "ReferenceError: Subscription is not defined".

The error is comming from "SubjectSubscription.js.pre-build-optimizer.js"

here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "node", "core-js" ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [ "../src/**/*" ],
  "exclude": [ "../bin", "../node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

here is my tsconfig.app.json (for prod build)

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

here is my package.json

```
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "6.0.3",
"@angular/common": "6.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "6.0.3",
"@angular/core": "6.0.3",
"@angular/forms": "6.0.3",
"@angular/http": "6.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.3",
"@angular/platform-server": "6.0.3",
"@angular/pwa": "^0.8.9",
"@angular/router": "6.0.3",
"@angular/service-worker": "6.0.3",
"@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.3",
"@aspnet/signalr-protocol-msgpack": "^1.0.3",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
"angular-2-local-storage": "^2.0.0",
"angular-archwizard": "^3.0.0",
"angular-confirmation-popover": "^4.1.0",
"angular2-notifications": "^1.0.2",
"angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"chart.js": "^2.7.2",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"file-saver": "^1.3.8",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"ng-sidebar": "^8.0.0",
"ng-spin-kit": "^5.1.1",
"ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
"ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
"ng2-select": "^2.0.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
"ngx-mydatepicker": "^2.4.5",
"ngx-ui-switch": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
"primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
"primeng": "^6.0.0-beta.1",
"quill": "^1.3.6",
"rxjs": "^6.2.0",
"text-mask-addons": "^3.7.2",
"typings": "^2.1.1",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.12.3",
"@angular/cli": "^6.0.7",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.3",
"@angular/language-service": "6.0.3",
"@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "^3.1.4",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "^5.4.2",
"ts-node": "~4.1.0",
"tslint": "^5.10.0",
"typescript": "2.7.2"
},
"optionalDependencies": {
  "node-sass": "^4.9.0"
}
```

Comment: Make sure you imported Subscription from rxjs

Comment: @Christian the problem ins't in any of my ts files, it is inside a internal file of rxjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating RxJs to 6.2.2 solved the issue.

```
"rxjs": "6.2.2",
```

I think the problem was related with @angular-devkit, it have a requirement of rxjs 6.2.2

```
"@angular-devkit/architect": {
      "version": "0.8.9",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit/architect/-/architect-0.8.9.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-2tiGPkvJyFY/G3a27uC8r6Jj3H5m8SxjMqhjNUQ5AtNumweTBPt3YIYMNAvHUmxG0nA9upDolVXFmoQGK9AhKQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "@angular-devkit/core": "0.8.9",
        "rxjs": "6.2.2"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "rxjs": {
          "version": "6.2.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs/-/rxjs-6.2.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-0MI8+mkKAXZUF9vMrEoPnaoHkfzBPP4IGwUYRJhIRJF6/w3uByO1e91bEHn8zd43RdkTMKiooYKmwz7RH6zfOQ==",
          "dev": true,
          "requires": {
            "tslib": "^1.9.0"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```